# Вход на сайт под другим человеком

Tags: cookie, аутентификация, авторизация, authenticationtoken

При открытии сайта вводится логин и пароль, сервер присылает в ответе токен для авторизации в браузер, пользователь входит на сайт. Если заходится на данный сайт с этого компьютера, то он уже не просит введения логина и пароля. Возможно ли забрать информацию из cookie браузера и использовать ее на другом компьютере, зайти/авторизоваться на данный сайт по видом данного пользователя. Возможно ли это сделать? Как по шагам это сделать?

Comment: Зачем это нужно?

Comment: Хочет дать кому-то доступ, но не давать пароль. Ну это тебе кукки нужны(там обычно хранится информация).

Comment: На сервере может быть привязка к IP-адресу, поэтому, в общем случае, это сделать невозможно.